# Disable log color for file appender, enable for console

Tags: logging, rust

I am working on my first Rust app, and I want to log to both `stdout` as well as a file. I want the console logs to include ANSI colors, but don't want those escape codes in the text output. Is this possible? I have been digging through the docs and code for log4rs, and I can't find any way to turn colors on or off at all, much less for a particular appender.

Here is the logger and appender setup I have thus far:

```rs
pub fn init() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let pattern = "[{d(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}][{T:<12.12}][{l:<5.5}] {m}\n";

    let logfile = RollingFileAppender::builder()
        .encoder(Box::new(PatternEncoder::new(pattern)))
        .build(
            "logs/output.log",
            Box::new(
                CompoundPolicy::new(
                    Box::new(SizeTrigger::new(1024 * 1024 * 10)),
                    Box::new(log4rs::append::rolling_file::policy::compound::roll::fixed_window::FixedWindowRoller::builder().build("log/output.log.{}", 10).unwrap())
                )
            )
        )?;
    let stdout = ConsoleAppender::builder()
        .encoder(Box::new(PatternEncoder::new(pattern)))
        .build();

    let config = Config::builder()
        .appender(Appender::builder().build("stdout", Box::new(stdout)))
        .appender(Appender::builder().build("logfile", Box::new(logfile)))
        .build(Root::builder()
            .appender("logfile")
            .appender("stdout")
            .build(LevelFilter::Info))?;

    log4rs::init_config(config)?;

    Ok(())
}
```